# Why Won't This Station Accept Mail?

Tags: openttd

[image: Open TTD screenshot.] Each of those buildings give 1/4 Mail (or 2/8, if you want to get technical.) The station's range is about five squares.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A bus station can only accept and supply passengers. To accept mail, or any other goods, you'll need to build a lorry station. Bus and lorry stations can be part of the same station complex, so building a lorry station in an adjacent square will allow the station complex to accept mail and passengers, but mail vehicles will only go to the lorry station and passenger vehicles to the bus station.